# Android kotlin reorder recyclerview with ItemTouchHelper calling function while item is held

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view, its list is stored in firestore. I want to allow user to reorder the items using drag and drop. When the user removes the hold (drops the item) I want to call the function to update the firestore but whenever the position is changed even while dragging to the desired position the function is getting called. How can I call the function only when the item is placed.

```
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(
        object: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0){
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                source: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                val sourcePosition = source.adapterPosition
                val targetPosition = target.adapterPosition

                Collections.swap(itemList, sourcePosition, targetPosition)
                adapter.notifyItemMoved(sourcePosition, targetPosition)

// Firestore update
                updateFirestoreList()

                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

When you selected to drag, store this position

```
var sourcePosition = -1
override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
     super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
     if(actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE){
           sourcePosition = viewHolder!!.adapterPosition
     }
}
```

When you drop `clearView` will be called, get position of ViewHolder and swap Collection

```
override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
    val targetPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    if(sourcePosition != -1 && sourcePosition != targetPosition){
        Collections.swap(itemList, sourcePosition, targetPosition)
    }
    sourcePosition = -1
}
```

I hope it helps :))

Comment: Perhaps this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)) might help. At least to see how you get the position of an item.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I achieved it was by overriding the `clearView()` method of `ItemTouchHelper`, and calling a callback from it. It would be something like below:

```kotlin
class MyTouchHelper(val onActionEnded: () -> Unit) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(UP or DOWN, 0) {

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    ): Boolean {
        recyclerView.adapter?.let { adapter ->
            adapter as MyListAdapter
            val from = viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition
            val to = target.absoluteAdapterPosition
            adapter.onItemMoved(from, to)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}

    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
        onActionEnded()
    }
}
```

<s>The `onItemMovied(from, to)`, is a function in the `MyListAdapter` class that is having an implementation like the below:</s>

```kotlin
fun onItemMoved(from: Int, to: Int) {
    val list = currentList.toMutableList()
    list.add(to, list.removeAt(from))
    submitList(list)
}
```

It just updates the list with the new item's position(you might have a different approach, feel free to use it according to your need or not to use it at all). @viethoang [implementation for updating the list itself seems more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76714108/5780236). I'd suggest giving it a try.

And finally, where you are attaching the `MyTouchHelper`, you can use its callback to call your specific function like below:

```kotlin
ItemTouchHelper(MyTouchHelper {
    updateFirestoreList()// Or any other functions that you want.
}).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `ItemMoveCallback` for that.

```
class ItemMoveCallback(var mAdapter: ItemTouchHelperContract) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {}

    override fun getMovementFlags(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Int {
        val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE)
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        mAdapter.onRowMoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSelectedChanged(
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
        actionState: Int
    ) {
        if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (viewHolder is RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
                val myViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = viewHolder
                mAdapter.onRowSelected(myViewHolder)
            }
        }
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
    }

    override fun clearView(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
        val myViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = viewHolder
        mAdapter.onRowClear(myViewHolder)
    }

    interface ItemTouchHelperContract {
        fun onRowMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int)
        fun onRowSelected(myViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?)
        fun onRowClear(myViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?)
    }
}
```

Now, in your recyclerview adapter,

```
class MYAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>, ItemMoveCallback.ItemTouchHelperContract {

.........
.........

override fun onRowMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
                Collections.swap(itemsList, i, i + 1)
            }
        } else {
            for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
                Collections.swap(itemsList, i, i - 1)
            }
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    }

    override fun onRowSelected(myViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
        binding.root.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
        // Apply the logic of notifying the user that item is selected here.
    }

    override fun onRowClear(myViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
        binding.root.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        yourListenerToUpdateData?.onDataReordered(itemsList)
    }

}
```